# displaying anchor tag with both block and table-cell features

Tags: css, hyperlink

So, I have the following code:

```
<div class="flexslider" id="carousel">
    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li class="thumbnail">
            <a href="#">Really long link that happens to move to multiple lines</a>
        </li>
        <li class="thumbnail">
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="thumbnail">
            <a href="#">Link 3 </a>
        </li>
        <li class="thumbnail">
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with the folllowing CSS:

```
.flexslider ul.thumbs {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
}

.flexslider li.thumbnail {
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    border-right: solid 1px #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.flexslider li.thumbnail a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: auto 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The problem is this. I want the link to fill the entire area - thus the `display: block;`. However, I also want the text to `vertical-align: middle;`. However, if I have the display set to block, it fills the area, but doesn't vertically align the text. If I change the display to table-cell, the text aligns properly, but the `a` doesn't fill the entire `li`. I can't figure out how to make it do both.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the line height to be the height of the li.
Check it!

http://codepen.io/tylerism/pen/NqXLJm

```
.flexslider li.thumbnail a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height:100px;   
}
```

EDIT: I updated [my codepen](http://codepen.io/tylerism/pen/yNpxpm). 
I am using a bit of a hack where I put the anchor tag on the outside of the li. Does this work for you?

Comment: That worked beautifully except on the link that spans more than one line.

Comment: yes, except now each item spans the entire UL. I'll work on tweaking it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you like to use `padding`?

```
.flexslider li.thumbnail a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 25% 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

How about using a `table-cell` instead of a `block`?

```css
.flexslider ul.thumbs {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
}

.flexslider li.thumbnail {
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    border-right: solid 1px #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.flexslider li.thumbnail a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexslider" id="carousel">
    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li class="thumbnail">
            <a href="#">Really long link that happens to move to multiple lines</a>
        </li>
        <li class="thumbnail">
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="thumbnail">
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="thumbnail">
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That will work, but when the text drops to multiple lines the other items are off center.

Comment: It actually even throws my single line links off. :(

Comment: I need to use block because I want the whole area to be linked, not just the words.

Comment: @ReverendDovie Using a `table-cell` will still linked the whole area, but the choice is yours.

Comment: @tylerism Why didn't you realize that in [your first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31120746/1) which is more worst? :)

Comment: @5ervant On my screen the text was not dropping to the next line, and it looked fine. Then he replied that it was not working well. Then I saw your answer, and noticed that it also wouldn't do what he wanted, so I was trying to save ya some time :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using line-height

https://jsfiddle.net/6w244Lm1/

```
.flexslider ul.thumbs {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
display: table;
height: 100px;
}

.flexslider li.thumbnail {
list-style: none;
width: 25%;
height: 100px;
display: table-cell;
border-right: solid 1px #000;
text-align: center;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
line-height: 100px;
}

.flexslider li.thumbnail a {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: auto 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```